# type const ref function const?

Tags: c++, function, constants, ref

I'm a bit confused by the 2 appearances of const here, what does this mean?

Can this format be applied to other objects?

```
...
T const & GetAt(size_t const index) const
{
    if (index < Size) return data[index];
    throw std::out_of_range("index out of range");
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`const` in `T const &` means that this method returns constant reference to T.
`const` in parameter means that index parameter is constant.
`const` after parameter list means that method may be called on constant object or constant reference/pointer to object i.e.:

```
const YourClass obj;

YourClass const & cref = obj.

obj.GetAt(10);// no compile error.

cref.GetAt(10);// no compile error either.
```

If method is not constant then calling it on constant object/reference/pointer will lead to compile error.

For other usage of `const` read this article https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/const

Answer (score 0):

T ***const*** & -> returns a const reference of type T, means a reference that you can access from outside of this function, but const means you cannot modify it.

(size_t ***const*** index)  -> the parameter `index` is const and cannot be modified from within the function

GetAt(size_t const index) **const** -> the method `GetAt` cannot modify any members in the class and it cannot call non-const-qualified method.
You can say that it does not modify the state of the class.